# how to apply function to each column in dataframe of R

Tags: r, dataframe

I want to apply a function to each column in R. Suppose following is the dataframe with (3xn):

```r
df <- data.frame(
  h1 = c(1,2,3),
  h2 = c(2,3,1),
  h3 = c(3,2,1),
  h4 = c(1,2,3),
  h5 = c(1,2,3)
)
rownames(df) <- c("e1", "e2", "e3")
df
#    h1 h2 h3 h4 h5
# e1  1  2  3  1  1
# e2  2  3  2  2  2
# e3  3  1  1  3  3
```

if we want to check if the first 2 elements suppose (e1==1, e2==2) for each column (h1,h2...). How could we apply the checking function to each column in the data frame?

Comment: Please do not post an image of code/data/errors: it cannot be copied or searched (SEO), it breaks screen-readers, and it may not fit well on some mobile devices. Ref: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3358272 (and https://xkcd.com/2116/). Please just include the code or data (e.g., `dput(head(x))` or `data.frame(...)`) directly.

Comment: @r2evans When it was posted first, it was not an image though.  I think it got edited

Comment: You don't have permissions yet to show an image. But if you put it in with that intent, typically somebody edits your question to actually show the image. **But my point** is that an image of data does me (and others) no good, and I categorically won't spend time transcribing data from an image into usable code or data. It is just as easy (perhaps easier) for you to copy text from your R console and paste into a [code-block](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting) than to get a screenshot and post it in as an image.

Comment: In general, *"apply function to each column"* is literally `lapply(dataframe, myfunc)`. akrun's suggestion to use `colSums` is one of the special cases, and is much more efficient in this situation.

Comment: For the record, after taking the sample data in alex_jwb90's answer (and changing to `data.frame`), this question is a bit more easily reproducible. I kept the row names solely because you referenced them as `e1==1`, etc; note that many operations on frames will not preserve row names, including just about everything within the `tidyverse` meta-package; so while I can see some utility in row names in general (and it can be a polarizing opinion for some), I normally don't use or rely on them.

Answer (score 3):

Subset the rows of the data based on either `row.names` or the `head`, compare `==` with a vector of values, get the `colSums` of the logical `matrix` derived from it and check if that is equal to 2 i.e. if both the elements are `TRUE` for each column

```
colSums(mat[c("e1", "e2"),] == c(1, 2))==2
```

---

Or with `apply`, loop over the columns `(MARGIN = 2`), apply the function (anonymous function call) and check if `all` are `TRUE` from the comparison

```
apply(head(mat, 2), 2, function(x) all(x  == c(1, 2)))
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. But, I have to do something like following and hence need to use apply/lapply/sapply function in R:                                             
rank.shape = function(x) {
    # i here  ranges from 1 to 5 which is the number of columns                                                                                                                           
    df = NA
    if (x[1,][i]==2 && x[2,][i]==1){
        //....
    }
    else if(x[1,][i]==2 && x[2,][i]==1.5){
        //....)  }
  list.shape = lapply(matrixRanks[1,], rank.shape)

Comment: @ChimiWangmo  I answered for the question posted

Comment: Chimi, that much code in a comment doesn't always format well. Further, you explicitly say you need to use one of the apply family of functions, so please be clear in your question. Using "apply" as a verb does not clearly indicate using `apply` as a function.

Answer (score 3):

Using @alex_jwb90's data,

```r
lapply(df, function(a) a[1:2] == 1:2)
# $h1
# [1] TRUE TRUE
# $h2
# [1] FALSE FALSE
# $h3
# [1] FALSE  TRUE
# $h4
# [1] TRUE TRUE
# $h5
# [1] TRUE TRUE

lapply(df, function(a) all(a[1:2] == 1:2))
# $h1
# [1] TRUE
# $h2
# [1] FALSE
# $h3
# [1] FALSE
# $h4
# [1] TRUE
# $h5
# [1] TRUE

sapply(df, function(a) all(a[1:2] == 1:2))
#    h1    h2    h3    h4    h5 
#  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this
(extensible to check more than two rows if you remove the `& row_number() <= 2`)

```
library(dplyr)

df = tibble(
  h1 = c(1,2,3),
  h2 = c(2,3,1),
  h3 = c(3,2,1),
  h4 = c(1,2,3),
  h5 = c(1,2,3)
)

df %>%
  mutate_all(
    list(equals_rownum = ~.==row_number() & row_number() <= 2)
  )
```

If you don't want to create new columns `<col>_equals_rownum` but replace h1,h2,...-columns, just remove the name in the `list`-call.